# API versioning for active models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activemodel, api-versioning

I am building a application in which i have a model user, In the first version of the application there will be no mobile number column for the users in the later version it must be present, is there any way to add versioning to models so that active record validation can be written to a particular version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the old users intact and subclass the new users. Since ActiveRecord supports Single Table Inheritance, the database will have a new column called `type` to distinguish between old a new users. And your validation will be only on the new users.

Keeping them as different classes mirrors your business model that the old users do not have a mobile phone number.

Comment: That may be one of the solution, but what i am expecting is is there any way of adding versioning to active models for mentioning the validation rather than adding a column to the table, for example having `validates_presense_of :mobile_number` only for the second version.

Comment: If one *version* behaves differently from another version, you either put conditions in your code (`if` or [`case`](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_expressions.html#S5) statements) or you use inheritance and polymorphic methods to express the differences. Since all new users can be used whenever the code expects an old user, I believe new users **are** old users per the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).